# Azure DevOps - Check if logged user has dark theme enabled

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I'm building an extension for Azure DevOps and I need to find out if the logged-in user has dark mode enabled.

Is there any way to do this through the Azure DevOps REST API or the VSS SDK?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to do this through the Azure DevOps REST API or the VSS SDK?

There is no such document REST API to check if logged user has dark theme enabled.

But we could use <kbd>F12</kbd> to grab the request URL:

```
Get  https://dev.azure.com/<YourOrganizationName>/_apis/Settings/Entries/globalme
```

The result from postman, if logged user has dark theme **enabled**, the value should be **`ms.vss-web.vsts-theme-dark`**

[image]

If not, the value should be default value `ms.vss-web.vsts-theme` without the `dark`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but when I make the request in postman it shows that I have the dark mode enabled, but I don't actually do

Comment: @nunolima41, Could you please double check this? It work fine on my side. Would you update the info and image in your question?